# how to change Jtextbox values without using Jbutton using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

I want to create a small **Netbeans** application related to school students. I have two *JTextFields*. In this *JTextFields* I want to show some words like **"apple"**, then want to show ***"mango"*** etc.

The details are as follows.

1. When the application is start I want to show in JtextField1 as ***"apple"***.
   When the student type it as same or wrong entry then auto move to next word ***"mango"*** in same  JTextfield1.
2. In this application JButton will not be use.

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have two JTextFields, one that the user is not supposed to edit and is for display only -- so make that field non-editable by

1. calling `setFocusable(false)` so the JTextField can never receive focus
2. And if you desire, calling `setEditable(false)`

In your 2nd JTextField, give it an ActionListener via `addActionListener(...)` that inside of the listener have the code check the 2nd JTextField's text and if incorrect, change the text in the first JTextField.

```
firstTextField.setFocusable(false);
firstTextField.setEditable(false);

secondTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = secondTextField.getText();

        // here check the text String and if incorrect
        // call setText(...) on the firstTextField
    }
});
```

Note that by adding an ActionListener to the JTextField itself, you now have a listener that is activated when the user presses the enter button when this field has focus. No need for a JButton for this to work.

Comment: @user5840896: and I have updated the answer, please note it.

Comment: @user5840896: if you are still stuck, then you will have to show your pertinent code and explain just where/how you're stuck.

Comment: full Eels I not getting any proper code for it.

I just tell you what i need in simple way.

For exmaple  In textbox text="apple" when click on enter text = "mango" then press enter text="abcd" like that. I am expecting you got the idea

Comment: @user5840896: please clarify as I don't understand what you've posted above. Again, I suggest that you try my suggestions above. If it doesn't work, ***post the code that you have***, that you've used to try to solve this, and describe the problems you're having with it. Without seeing your code, we're dead in the water.  We need to see it.